# Popular error - org.sqlite.JDBC in apache netbeans 11.2

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, netbeans

I know that this is a very common question, but I search a lot about it but cannot resolve my issue.

```
public static Connection connectDB(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn;
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:\\JAVA GUI\\Library\\library.sqlite");
        return conn;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

it shows error

> ClassNotFoundException org.sqlite.JDBC

I also installed and set a JDBC connector driver in Apache Netbeans, but still in vain. I am trying this from the last 2 days, but .
How can I fix this issue?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: The error means that you don't have the sqlite JDBC driver on the classpath of your application at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

For this issue i recommend to use this class and test, if you have a output data your connections is OK but it doesn't show anything verify your driver

For Sqlite

```
package net.sqlitetutorial;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author sqlitetutorial.net
 */
public class Connect {
     /**
     * Connect to a sample database
     */
    public static void connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            // db parameters
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db/chinook.db";
            // create a connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        connect();
    }
}
```

Article: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/

For Oracle

```
importjava.sql.*; 
importjava.util.*; 
class Main 
{ 
    public static void main(String a[]) 
    { 
        //Creating the connection 
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"; 
        String user = "system"; 
        String pass = "12345"; 

        //Entering the data 
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("enter name"); 
        String name = k.next(); 
        System.out.println("enter roll no"); 
        int roll = k.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("enter class"); 
        String cls =  k.next(); 

        //Inserting data using SQL query 
        String sql = "insert into student1 values('"+name+"',"+roll+",'"+cls+"')"; 
        Connection con=null; 
        try
        { 
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()); 

            //Reference to connection interface 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass); 

            Statement st = con.createStatement(); 
            int m = st.executeUpdate(sql); 
            if (m == 1) 
                System.out.println("inserted successfully : "+sql); 
            else
                System.out.println("insertion failed"); 
            con.close(); 
        } 
        catch(Exception ex) 
        { 
            System.err.println(ex); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Check this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/establishing-jdbc-connection-in-java/

Comment: Bro, Not helpful!

Comment: This in no way addresses the actual question.